# How do i add two giving numbers together in html

Tags: javascript, html

So my code just adds them together if i put like 4+4 it gives me 44 but i wanted to be like 4+4=8

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Laskeminen</title>
<body>

<script language="JavaScript">
first = prompt("Enter your first number.");
last = prompt("Enter your second number.");
</script>

<p id="first,last"></p>

<script>
var y = first
var z = last
var x = y + z;
document.getElementById("first,last").innerHTML = x;
</script> 

</head>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Number()` :

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Laskeminen</title>
<body>

<script language="JavaScript">
first = prompt("Enter your first number.");
last = prompt("Enter your second number.");
</script>

<p id="first,last"></p>

<script>
var y = Number(first);
var z = Number(last);
var x = y + z;
document.getElementById("first,last").innerHTML = x;
</script> 

</head>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `parseInt()`

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Laskeminen</title>
<body>

<script language="JavaScript">
first = prompt("Enter your first number.");
last = prompt("Enter your second number.");
</script>

<p id="first,last"></p>

<script>
var y = parseInt(first)
var z = parseInt(last)
var x = y + z;
document.getElementById("first,last").innerHTML = x;
</script> 

</head>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your second addition script you need to parse your input because currently it is a string.
See below

```js
first = prompt("Enter your first number.");
console.log('User input is: ', typeof first)
```

so because these are string when your adding text they get added together e.g.

```js
var text = 'ab';
var text1 = 'c';
if(text+text1 == 'abc'){
console.log('These have been added together and are equal')
}
```

So you need to parse now if your dealing with ints or whole numbers you can use `parseInt(**variabletoParse**)`
or `parseFloat(**variabletoParse**);`

So what you need to do can be seen blow:

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Laskeminen</title>
<body>

<script language="JavaScript">
first = prompt("Enter your first number.");
last = prompt("Enter your second number.");
</script>

<p id="first,last"></p>

<script>
var y = parseFloat(first);
var z = parseFloat(last);
var x = y + z;
document.getElementById("first,last").innerHTML = x;
</script> 

</head>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `parseFloat()` on the values to convert it into mathematical float values that can perform mathematical operation:

```js
var first = prompt("Enter your first number.");
var last = prompt("Enter your second number.");

var y = parseFloat(first);
var z = parseFloat(last);
var x = y + z;
document.getElementById("first,last").innerHTML = x;
```

```html
<p id="first,last"></p>
```

But if you want only `integers` then you can do `parseInt()`:

```js
var first = prompt("Enter your first number.");
var last = prompt("Enter your second number.");

var y = parseInt(first);
var z = parseInt(last);
var x = y + z;
document.getElementById("first,last").innerHTML = x;
```

```html
<p id="first,last"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   <html>
<head>
<title>Laskeminen</title>
<body>
<p id="first,last"></p>
<script language="JavaScript">
first = prompt("Enter your first number.");
last = prompt("Enter your second number."); 
var y = parseInt(first);
var z = parseInt(last);
var x = y + z;
document.getElementById("first,last").innerHTML = x;
</script> 

</head>
</body>

</body>
</html>
```